# Prove by induction that $1 \cdot 1!+2 \cdot 2!+\ldots+n \cdot n!=(n+1)!-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I am stuck at the inductive step. After much effort I arrived at $2(k+1)!+k(k+1)!-1$ but don't know how to go from there to $((k+1)+1!)-1$. I realise that I must express it in terms of $k+1$, but don't know how to manipulate the expression any further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: expressing $k\cdot k!$ as $((k+1)-1)\cdot k!$ is a cleaner approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a commont factor $ (k+1)! $,
$$ 2(k+1)! + k(k+1)! - 1 = (k+2)(k+1)! - 1 = (k+2)! -1. $$

Answer (score 2):

Say we have  $1.1!+2.2!…+(n-1).(n-1)!=n!-1$ for $n$. Then we will check it out  for $n+1$.
Since 
$(n+1)!= (n+1).n!=n.n!+n!$
then we have the equality $ (n+1)!-1=n.n!+n!-1$ 
and with induction hypothesis we get the last step $(n+1)!-1=n.n!+(n-1).(n-1)!+\ldots+1.1!$